# Receiving packets from Amazon

Tags: virus, wireshark, packet

I ran a Wireshark packet capture on my home Windows PC, as there was some suspicion that I was infected (although I notice nothing out of the ordinary and both Avast and Malwarebytes detect nothing).

Just to be sure, I ran this capture overnight, and noticed packets from sources such as Akamai, Amazon and Microsoft (according to ARIN). Should I be worried? Here is a print screen focusing in on the dubious packet.

[image]

Comment: Those are all normal traffic.

Comment: @schroeder (^) Thank you, but could you elaborate as to what it is?

Comment: Without seeing what the content is (seeing the packets) there is not much to elaborate on. It could all be normal "phone home" traffic of Windows.

Comment: Akamai/Microsoft, pffft, it's continuous and increases mightily under Windows 8-10. What Amazon products do you have installed?

Comment: I do not think I have any Amazon products installed. @FiascoLabs I can post the packet capture screeenshot

Comment: There is a partial hexdump of the largest packet i received

Comment: Most of your traffic is staying within your network or going to the same address, which tells me, it's normal Windows Update traffic.

Comment: @FiascoLabs You don't have to have an Amazon product to receive Amazon traffic. AWS for example is Amazon's cloud service can be used just by about anyone or anything. Akamai is also another cloud service. Both are used by many websites, services, and programs even by well known, trusted, and common pieces of software. Or in the case of the body information this appears another program is using Amazon's APIs. Like Schroeder states I suspect there is nothing malicious with this traffic.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a large number of organizations, search engines, and bots which are scanning the entire Internet on a regular basis to see what ports are open and what versions of services exist. An example of a site doing this type of work is [scans.io](https://scans.io/) Most of this activity is not harmful.

There are even tools like [masscan](https://github.com/robertdavidgraham/masscan) and [Zmap](https://zmap.io/) which allow anyone to scan the entire IPv4 space for a given port/service in just a few minutes and you can see samples of the types of data collected at sites like [scans.io](https://scans.io/)

Without more information about the packets themselves it would be very hard to tell you if these were malicious in nature but most likely this is just typical Internet traffic. That said it would be wise to dig a little deeper and see if this is related to process activity on your system and see if your system, or the software on it, isn't the source for this activity.

Comment: Can they really scan the entire IPv4 space? I doubt it.

Comment: Absolutely. Check out the links and try it yourself. IPv4 is easy. IPv6 is hard

Comment: @uoɥʇʎPʎzɐɹC Not only can they, it's routine.  Robert Graham, for one, (the creator of masscan) does it all the time for various research projects.

Comment: I feel like someone could launch a DoS attack using this - but if it hasn't been done, surely it's not possible, right?

Comment: There are better tools + you'd still need a lot of bandwidth if it's a brute-force DoS.. Not that you couldn't use it though.

Answer (score 1):

While it is always possible that there is a malware Command and Control (C&C) server hosted on an Amazon ec2 or Microsoft cloud it is rather unlikely as such things are usually hosted on so called "Bullet Proof Hosts" that ignore take down orders. What is likely causing these requests is applications you have installed that make api calls as well as Windows looking for updates. That being said you are most likely not infected by any common large scale malware. This is not to say that you are not infected by something that was specifically targeted but if you do not have reason to suspect something like that is the case you are most likely find.

Answer (score 1):

These are connections started from your Windows machine; note the SYN packet from 192.168.1.160 to an external address and how your machine sends an HTTP request.

The packet you've highlighted is part of the response (503 Server Unavailable) to your HTTP query. If you right-click into it and choose "Follow TCP Stream" you'll see a reconstruction of the HTTP conversation in ASCII.

They look harmless to me and are probably part of some application (or OS component) you have installed.